# NumPyArrayToFeatureClass gives RuntimeError: create table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, numpy

I've tried to change polygon feautre  to point by using tools:

FeatureClassToNumPyArray
NumPyArrayToFeatureClass.
My code as below:

```
    import arcpy
    import numpy as np
    in_file='C:/ios/OneDrive/siatki_obliczeniowe/siatki.gdb/siatka_005'
    a = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(in_file, ["*"], explode_to_points=False)
    out_file='C:/ios/OneDrive/siatki_obliczeniowe/siatki.gdb/xxxx3'

    arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(a, out_file,["shape"])
```

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ios/OneDrive/python/feature_to_point.py", line 7, in <module>
    arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(a, out_file,["shape"])
RuntimeError: create table
```

I had changed out_file to shp file and it works but it is not solution for me. I would like to be able write to .gdb.
Any idea how to solve this problem?

I modified my code as below:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
in_file='C:/ios/OneDrive/siatki_obliczeniowe/siatki.gdb/strefy_miejskie_siatka_01'
flds = ['OID@', 'SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y']
other_flds = [i.name for i in arcpy.ListFields(in_file) if i.type not in ('OID', 'Geometry')]
flds.extend(other_flds)
a = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(in_file, flds, explode_to_points=False)
out_file='C:/ios/OneDrive/siatki_obliczeniowe/siatki.gdb/axxxyz9'
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(a, out_file,['SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y'])
```

**Unfortunately I got the same error again.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NumPyArrayToFeatureClass](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/numpyarraytofeatureclass.htm) writes out a point FeatureClass. If you look at the sample code at the end of the help file you will see that they reference the geometry by XY.

What is your input dataset, is it a polygon, you don't specify a centroid for your polygon when you run [FeatureClassToNumPyArray](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/featureclasstonumpyarray.htm). Look at the syntax section of the help file to understand what you are writing to the array, you have accepted the default * and not actually the geometry.

EDIT:

On further investigation of the updated code I worked out the error is caused because you exported all fields and you can't write back to a GEODATABASE featureclass the length and area fields as they are protected and maintained by the geodatabase. By adding these lines after you create `flds` list your code will now work:

```
flds.remove(u"Shape_Length")
flds.remove(u"Shape_Area")
```

Comment: Yes, my input is polygon.

Comment: Yes, my input is polygon. My biggest doubt is the code works when you change out_file='C:/ios/OneDrive/siatki_obliczeniowe/siatki.gdb/xxxx3' to out_file='C:/ios/OneDrive/siatki_obliczeniowe/xxxx3.shp'.

Comment: So what do you get in the shapefile, what sort of geometry comes out ?

Comment: Point shapefile with attributes from polygon feature

Comment: Hmm, may be you have too explicitly state that you want to write out XY for a FeatureClass?

Comment: To answer you I edited the quesion. As you can see it doesn't work.

Comment: @Grzegorz see my updated answer